# Python double underscore mangling

Tags: python, attributes, python-3.x, private-methods, double-underscore

I am a bit confused by this behavior (using python 3.2):

```
class Bar:
    pass

bar = Bar()
bar.__cache = None
print(vars(bar))        # {'__cache': None}

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__cache = None

foo = Foo()
print(vars(foo))        # {'_Foo__cache': None}
```

I've read up a bit on how double-underscores cause attribute names to be "mangled", but I would have expected the same name-mangling in both cases above.

[What is the meaning of a single- and a double-underscore before an object name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python)

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: The point of mangling is precisely to **prevent** your second case from working correctly. The intent is to hide the attribute from external code.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Name mangling occurs during the evaluation of a `class` statement. In the case of `Bar`, the `__cache` attribute is not defined as part of the class, but rather added to a specific object after the fact.

(Actually, that may not be entirely correct. Name mangling may occur during the evaluation of the `__new__` method; I do not know. But regardless, your `__cache` is added explicitly to a single object, not added by the class code.)

Comment: It's mangled during compilation. You can use the `dis.dis()` function to see this, just run the `import dis; dis.dis(Foo.__init__)` to see that the name has already been mangled.

Answer (score 11):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html?highlight=mangling#index-5)

> Private name mangling: *When an identifier that textually occurs in a
>   class definition* begins with two or more underscore characters and
>   does not end in two or more underscores, it is considered a private
>   name of that class. Private names are transformed to a longer form
>   before code is generated for them. The transformation inserts the
>   class name in front of the name, with leading underscores removed, and
>   a single underscore inserted in front of the class name. For example,
>   the identifier `__spam` occurring in a class named Ham will be
>   transformed to `_Ham__spam`. This transformation is independent of the
>   syntactical context in which the identifier is used. If the
>   transformed name is extremely long (longer than 255 characters),
>   implementation defined truncation may happen. If the class name
>   consists only of underscores, no transformation is done.

You are assigning your property after the class has been defined