# why can you inherit private functions from class object in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Cat:
    a=4

cat = Cat()
cat.__str__()
```

How come class Cat inherits the private functions `__str__()` and `__format__()` from `object`?

Isn't the point of private functions that you cannot inherit them?

Comment: dunders(double underscore) aren't private functions, and python doesn't have truly private functions anyways.

Comment: Double underscores at the end also change (pronounced: remove) the name mangling.

Comment: dunder = `__foo__`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How come class Cat inherits the private functions `__str__()` and `__format__()` from object?

To begin, these methods aren't actually private. Somewhat confusingly, python uses `__varname` for private variables/methods, while `__varname__` are **not** private, and can be considered magic methods or dunders, commonly used for operator overloading.

> Isn't the point of private functions that you cannot inherit them?

Not quite. A `__varname` private variable has the perception of not being inheritable:

```py
class Foo:
    def __foo(self):
        print("foo")

    def __init__(self):
        self.__foo() # prints foo

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__() # will print foo
        self.__foo() # will error saying no __foo method
```

But, this is merely due to python's [double underscore name mangling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498151/python-double-underscore-mangling). `__foo` in a class `Foo` becomes `_Foo__foo`, and it *is* inherited to `Bar`, but it keeps its `Foo` prefix. So, when you try to call `__foo` from `Bar`, it'll be mangled into `_Bar__foo`, which doesn't exist. If you replaced the `self.__foo()` line in `Bar` with `self._Foo__foo()`, then there would be no errors, and you'd be calling a "private" property.

See also:

- [Does Python have "private" variables in classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1641219/5923139)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `public` or `private` things in python. Everything is accessible from everywhere.

But there are naming conventions that indicates if the user should use or access members. See the [python.org section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#public-and-internal-interfaces)